# System.Thearding.TheardStateExeption:текущий поток должен быть задан как поток однопоточного контейнера <STA>

Tags: c#, .net

Как сделать так чтобы метод `Clipboard.Clear` работал? Сейчас выдает такую ошибку:

> System.Thearding.TheardStateExeption:текущий поток должен быть задан как поток однопоточного контейнера .

Код приложения:

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    [SerializableAttribute] [ComVisible(true)]
    public classThreadStateException : SystemException
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == true)
            {
                string someText = Clipboard.GetText();
                MessageBox.Show(someText, "Сообщение",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вбуфереобменанеттекста",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OKMessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что типы из пространства имен `System.Windows.Forms` интенсивно вызывают Win32-код, разработанный в расчете на работу в однопоточном апартаменте, об этом, в частности, говорится в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) на класс `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` (см. подразделы *Комментарии* и *Исключения*).

Для того, чтобы главный поток приложения вошел в однопоточный апартамент, пометьте метод `Main` атрибутом `[STAThread]`:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
```